# Failed to install ipywidgets jupyter lab extension

Tags: ipywidgets

I'm having trouble installing the ipywidgets jupyterlab extension. I tried following [this direction](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html), and I got the  message `Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)` as follows:

```
$  conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
$ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
$
```

After this process, I got an error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipywidgets'` as bellow.

[image: screen shot of a jupyter lab's window]

I tried to fix this issue with two methods.

1. I refered to [this page](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7180) as reference and I typed `jupyter lab build --minimize=False`. However, I got the same error message as before:

```
$ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
```

2. I referd to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210272/jupyterlab-plotly-build-npm-extensions-failed-to-install-on-linux) as reference. However, when I try `$which nodejs`, I didn't get any responses on terminal display.

How can I fix this problem and install ipywidgets?

Informationon my machine:

```
$ which node
/Users/myname/opt/miniconda3/envs/ptfl/bin/node
$ node -v 
v14.5.0
$ which nodejs
$ ls /usr/local/bin/node 
/usr/local/bin/node
$ which npm
/Users/myname/opt/miniconda3/envs/ptfl/bin/npm
$ npm -v 
6.14.5
```

About OS: MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4

About miniconda : miniconda3

==============================

**Update**

**7/25:**

1. I updated the OS from v10.15.14 to v10.15.5.
2. After updated the OS, I retried to install a ipywidgets as folllows.

=

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
 Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/myname/opt/miniconda3/envs/ptfl

  added / updated specs:
    - nodejs


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    nodejs-14.6.0              |       hdde0ff8_0        12.7 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        12.7 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  nodejs                                  14.5.0-h2c41780_0 --> 14.6.0-hdde0ff8_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
nodejs-14.6.0        | 12.7 MB   | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
$ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
```

Comment: "Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)" is not an error message, but rather a progress indicator. IF you saw no other error, things should be working as intended. Are there any other things that cause you to believe things are not working?

Comment: @Vidar Thank you for the information. I understood "Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)" is not an error message and edited this post. However, I still got an error message on jupyterlab "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipywidgets'". Do you have any how to fix this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you need to install the python module in your kernel (which has nothing to do with the lab extension).